# How to show POP UP window with message using Sikuli webdriver?

Tags: sikuli

I would like to show POP UP with message when my test runs successful. Pls suggest sikuli script for this.

Answer (score 4):

As @autoKarma suggested, you can easily use the popup() function. I have been working with sikuli quite a while. You can see this simple code below.

```
popup("Display your message here")
```

That's it. This simple code would serve your purpose.
Goodluck

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the popup() function? It is documented [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#interacting-with-the-user). I don't know anything about sikuli's interaction with webdriver, so take it for whatever its worth.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = input("message", "default", "titleOfPopup")
```

Comment: variable = input("message", "default", "titleOfPopup")         Sorry for the mistake

Comment: You can [edit] your post to correct mistakes. I have done so, but you could also add explanation as to why and how this works.